# Taking into account symmetry, how many possible games of tic-tac-toe are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Same as this other question ([Game combinations of tic-tac-toe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269066/game-combinations-of-tic-tac-toe)), but taking into account symmetry.

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to count them other than going through all possible games. It's a bit fewer if you only want to count final game boards, because the same board can be reached through several different games, but I don't think it's really any easier to count.

Answer (score 9):

In one sense, you could just take the answer of $255\,168$ to the previous problem and divide it by $8$, getting $31\,896$. If you care about the order in which the pieces were played, then a description of one complete tic-tac-toe might look like the board below:
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
   \times_1 & \bigcirc_2 & \times_3 \\
\hline
   & \times_7 & \bigcirc_4 \\
\hline
  \bigcirc_6 &  & \times_5
\end{array}
and all such descriptions with a three-in-a-row in them are asymmetric: so, because the tic-tac-toe board has eightfold symmetry (four possible rotations which may or may not be followed by a reflection), we can take symmetry into account just by dividing by $8$.

But you might also consider this game to be identical to the game represented by
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
   \times_1 & \bigcirc_2 & \times_3 \\
\hline
   \bigcirc_4 & \times_7 & \\
\hline
  \times_5 &  & \bigcirc_6
\end{array}
because the only distinguishing trait is that on $\bigcirc$'s second move, they played next to $\times$'s *first* mark, not next to their *second* mark, even though the two positions created in this way are symmetrical. In other words, after every move these two games were in identical positions up to symmetry - it's just that *which* symmetry this is changes over the course of the game.

[This page](http://www.mathrec.org/old/2002jan/solutions.html) lists the answer to possible variants of this question. The difference between the two notions of symmetry described above is **board symmetry** (which considers the two games above to be different) and **game symmetry** (which considers them to be the same).

Under game symmetry, the number of possible tic-tac-toe games is only $26\,830$.

The page I linked to above also lists several other possible answers we could give, under additional constraints:

- We could stop the game once the winner has been determined (or once it's been determined that the game is a draw).
- We could forbid the players from making "obviously stupid" moves, for different notions of "obviously stupid" (e.g., not making winning moves when they're available, or not *blocking* winning moves when the other player threatens to win).

Answer (score 0):

This question is a good introduction to symmetries because there are two symmetries of the board - both reflections and rotations - and we need to disentangle the two.

This is easy to do because although the board can be reflected on any of 4 axes (two central axes and two diagonals), all of these reflections are the same once we permit rotation since a flip of the board on any one choice of axis can easily be translated to be equivalent to having flipped on any of the other 3 axes, by an appropriate choice of rotation.

There are 4 rotational positions which leave the board itself unchanged, multiplied by one flipping axis (i.e. two possibilities) so there are 8 symmetries.

Dividing $255168$ by $8$ gives $31896$ possible games.

...This simple answer would count the $2$ games given in Misha's answer as different.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would throw this out there, I counted 46910 total game states including non-win non-draw situations like the empty board. #pyhtonFTW

> EDIT: If you assume that players will block if the opponent will win
>   next turn and also that players will win if they can I found a
>   decision tree with 6355 nodes, of the leaves, 488 are X wins, 1278 are
>   draw and, 164 are O wins. (X goes first.)

That said I think I actually over did it with my checking board transformations... For each possible move I check 16 possible board orientations, and apparently I only need to check 8...

I think I could just comment out lines; 8, 9, 58, 59.
[image]
https://github.com/Krewn/TicTacToe/blob/master/ttt.py

Comment: So, are the other two answers wrong or can you explain why your answer differs?